# Why am I seeing only an empty array when I view my app in browser after deploying to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I am working on deploying my backend rails app to Heroku. I followed all of the instructions, and as far as I know, my app has been deployed. However, when I open the app (in browser, via heroku), all I see is an empty array. When I navigate to https://warm-depths-26802.herokuapp.com/book_clubs, I should see a list of book clubs. But again, an empty array. The app is working fine locally.

I have looked at the Heroku logs and I don't see any errors:

```
2021-10-10T19:09:18.308324+00:00 heroku[release.2842]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c 'if curl https://heroku-release-output.s3.amazonaws.com/log-stream?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ3LIQ2SWG7V76SVQ%2F20211010%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211010T190916Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=94aad6f59f66a78d927f3de9dd81c416fd64f0d27de49d0664e4e5d954b4aabd --silent --connect-timeout 10 --retry 3 --retry-delay 1 >/tmp/log-stream; then
2021-10-10T19:09:18.916677+00:00 heroku[release.2842]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-10T19:09:19.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-10-10T19:09:20.776813+00:00 app[release.2842]:  (0.9ms)  SELECT pg_try_advisory_lock(7444242757272227025)
2021-10-10T19:09:20.789750+00:00 app[release.2842]:  (1.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
2021-10-10T19:09:20.797098+00:00 app[release.2842]: ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "ar_internal_metadata".* FROM "ar_internal_metadata" WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["key", "environment"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2021-10-10T19:09:20.801835+00:00 app[release.2842]:  (0.8ms)  BEGIN
2021-10-10T19:09:20.803262+00:00 app[release.2842]:  (0.9ms)  COMMIT
2021-10-10T19:09:20.804253+00:00 app[release.2842]:  (0.9ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(7444242757272227025)
2021-10-10T19:09:20.930358+00:00 heroku[release.2842]: Process exited with status 0
2021-10-10T19:09:20.968627+00:00 heroku[release.2842]: State changed from up to complete
2021-10-10T19:09:22.876680+00:00 app[api]: Release v20 created by user floramarina@comcast.net
2021-10-10T19:09:23.083604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-10-10T19:09:23.214839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-10-10T19:09:24.027464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-10-10T19:09:24.093951+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2021-10-10T19:09:24.096230+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2021-10-10 19:09:24 +0000 ===
2021-10-10T19:09:24.096232+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2021-10-10T19:09:24.096259+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2021-10-10T19:09:24.310123+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-10-10T19:09:25.243851+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails s`
2021-10-10T19:09:30.898425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-10T19:16:14.822994+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823036+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.6 application starting in production
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823037+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823037+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823038+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.1-p33), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823038+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823038+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823039+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:43234
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823039+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2021-10-10T19:16:14.823039+00:00 app[web.1]: [d13cec32-019d-407d-a583-bd1fb7418aea] Started GET "/" for 24.56.226.27 at 2021-10-10 19:16:14 +0000
2021-10-10T19:16:14.824019+00:00 app[web.1]: [d13cec32-019d-407d-a583-bd1fb7418aea] Processing by BookClubsController#index as HTML
2021-10-10T19:16:14.916619+00:00 app[web.1]: [d13cec32-019d-407d-a583-bd1fb7418aea]   BookClub Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "book_clubs".* FROM "book_clubs"
2021-10-10T19:16:14.930261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=warm-depths-26802.herokuapp.com request_id=d13cec32-019d-407d-a583-bd1fb7418aea fwd="24.56.226.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=113ms status=304 bytes=231 protocol=https
2021-10-10T19:16:14.931728+00:00 app[web.1]: [d13cec32-019d-407d-a583-bd1fb7418aea] Completed 200 OK in 108ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 41.7ms)
2021-10-10T19:16:18.253908+00:00 app[web.1]: [8c21a97a-80b9-413d-a589-2f47a902e8a3] Started GET "/book_clubs" for 24.56.226.27 at 2021-10-10 19:16:18 +0000
2021-10-10T19:16:18.254453+00:00 app[web.1]: [8c21a97a-80b9-413d-a589-2f47a902e8a3] Processing by BookClubsController#index as HTML
2021-10-10T19:16:18.255898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/book_clubs" host=warm-depths-26802.herokuapp.com request_id=8c21a97a-80b9-413d-a589-2f47a902e8a3 fwd="24.56.226.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=231 protocol=https
2021-10-10T19:16:18.257162+00:00 app[web.1]: [8c21a97a-80b9-413d-a589-2f47a902e8a3]   BookClub Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "book_clubs".* FROM "book_clubs"
2021-10-10T19:16:18.257894+00:00 app[web.1]: [8c21a97a-80b9-413d-a589-2f47a902e8a3] Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
2021-10-10T19:52:44.344436+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-10-10T19:52:44.367512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-10-10T19:52:45.021834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-10-10T19:52:45.697861+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2021-10-10T19:52:45.698295+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2021-10-10 19:52:45 +0000 ===
2021-10-10T19:52:45.698298+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2021-10-10T19:52:45.698348+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2021-10-10T19:52:45.848525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-10-10T20:29:44.901479+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-10-10T20:29:44.928905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-10-10T20:29:46.847167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails s`
2021-10-10T20:29:50.946126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977688+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977703+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.6 application starting in production
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977703+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977703+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977704+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.1-p33), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977704+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977704+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977704+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:47572
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977705+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2021-10-10T20:29:51.977712+00:00 app[web.1]: [8a7dcf6e-a502-4439-9328-b4895a4793b7] Started GET "/" for 24.56.226.27 at 2021-10-10 20:29:51 +0000
2021-10-10T20:29:51.978826+00:00 app[web.1]: [8a7dcf6e-a502-4439-9328-b4895a4793b7] Processing by BookClubsController#index as HTML
2021-10-10T20:29:52.037837+00:00 app[web.1]: [8a7dcf6e-a502-4439-9328-b4895a4793b7]   BookClub Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "book_clubs".* FROM "book_clubs"
2021-10-10T20:29:52.047841+00:00 app[web.1]: [8a7dcf6e-a502-4439-9328-b4895a4793b7] Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 34.2ms)
2021-10-10T20:29:52.049201+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=warm-depths-26802.herokuapp.com request_id=8a7dcf6e-a502-4439-9328-b4895a4793b7 fwd="24.56.226.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=74ms status=304 bytes=231 protocol=https
2021-10-10T21:04:54.072778+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-10-10T21:04:54.076057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-10-10T21:04:56.019287+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-10-10T21:04:56.090455+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2021-10-10T21:04:56.090942+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2021-10-10 21:04:56 +0000 ===
2021-10-10T21:04:56.090944+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2021-10-10T21:04:56.090999+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2021-10-10T21:04:56.272151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-10-10T21:40:55.490655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-10-10T21:40:55.503443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-10-10T21:40:57.340356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails s`
2021-10-10T21:41:01.396215+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-10-10T21:41:02.561990+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562066+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.2.6 application starting in production
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562066+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562066+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562066+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.12.6 (ruby 2.6.1-p33), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562067+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562067+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562067+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:32369
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562067+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562078+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c27fc9d-2b9d-4f04-bba9-e2bc86fd8d5d] Started GET "/" for 24.56.226.27 at 2021-10-10 21:41:02 +0000
2021-10-10T21:41:02.562948+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c27fc9d-2b9d-4f04-bba9-e2bc86fd8d5d] Processing by BookClubsController#index as HTML
2021-10-10T21:41:02.644470+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c27fc9d-2b9d-4f04-bba9-e2bc86fd8d5d]   BookClub Load (8.3ms)  SELECT "book_clubs".* FROM "book_clubs"
2021-10-10T21:41:02.657184+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=warm-depths-26802.herokuapp.com request_id=9c27fc9d-2b9d-4f04-bba9-e2bc86fd8d5d fwd="24.56.226.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=99ms status=304 bytes=231 protocol=https
2021-10-10T21:41:02.657223+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c27fc9d-2b9d-4f04-bba9-e2bc86fd8d5d] Completed 200 OK in 94ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 35.0ms)
2021-10-10T21:45:10.213461+00:00 app[web.1]: [beffde9a-3018-47ae-b3e5-50b985602411] Started GET "/book_clubs" for 24.56.226.27 at 2021-10-10 21:45:10 +0000
2021-10-10T21:45:10.214764+00:00 app[web.1]: [beffde9a-3018-47ae-b3e5-50b985602411] Processing by BookClubsController#index as HTML
2021-10-10T21:45:10.217905+00:00 app[web.1]: [beffde9a-3018-47ae-b3e5-50b985602411]   BookClub Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "book_clubs".* FROM "book_clubs"
2021-10-10T21:45:10.218260+00:00 app[web.1]: [beffde9a-3018-47ae-b3e5-50b985602411] Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
2021-10-10T21:45:10.219834+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/book_clubs" host=warm-depths-26802.herokuapp.com request_id=beffde9a-3018-47ae-b3e5-50b985602411 fwd="24.56.226.27" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=231 protocol=https
```

I've done a rake db:reset and then added an object to the database, so there should be only one book club that shows up. I've made sure the database is migrated on heroku. I've changed the default URL to the heroku URL. These are all suggestions I've seen while searching for answers to this question. It seems that others have run into this issue before.

Any ideas?

Comment: I looks like your DB is empty. How did you add an object to the database on heroku? Normally this would be either via a POST/PUT to a create route or via the `seeds.rb`.

Comment: You could try using a `heroku console` to access the remote machine, then you'll be able to check, and insert data into the remote system easily

Comment: What commands did you run to seed the production DB?  I assume it was along the lines of `heroku run rake db:seed` ?

Comment: @nlta I added an object via the seeds.rb file. I ran heroku run rake db:seed and got no errors, but still see just the empty array.

Comment: @RockwellRice yes, that's what I ran.